# Jacobian of mapping

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let's say we're in $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$ and we have the identity mapping $f:\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$, $f(x,y) = (x,y)$.

What I want to do is find the Jacobian determinant, but when starting I get a $2\times n$ matrix, not a square one. So, I have a basic misconception about how to find the Jacobian, I thought it would be $$J = \frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)}$$, but that doesn't seem to really be making sense.

Since it's a conceptual error, it's probably fine to just do $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, $f(x) = x$.

Hang on a second, I think I'm being dumb and am forgetting that component functions are a thing. I should probably sleep more.

---

So, to spell it out more, when $n=1$ we have:

$$f(x,y) = \big(f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y)\big),\text{ where } f_1(x,y)=x,f_2(x,y)=y $$
$$ \Rightarrow J=\frac{\partial(f_1,f_2)}{\partial(x,y)}=I_2$$

When $n=2$ we have:

$$f(x,y) = \big(f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y)\big),\text{ where } \\f_1(x,y)=x, f_2(x,y)=y$$

Comment: Do you still need help with this?

Comment: Something's not clicking.

Comment: @alg I would start by replacing $n$ with $1$, there seems to be part of what's generating your confusion.

Comment: I added a bit more to my answer. I'm not sure what to do with tuples of tuples.

Comment: The case $n=2$ doesn't apply here, it's senseless. For the case $n=2$ you'd need a function that mapped to $\mathbb R^n\times \mathbb R^n\color{gray}{\cong \mathbb R^4}$, which is not the case.

Comment: I'm confused. Why doesn't $\mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2 \cong \mathbb{R}^4$ make sense?

Comment: It makes sense, it doesn't make sense with $f(x,y)=(x,y)$. If you're thinking about a different $f$, you should use different letters.

Comment: Sorry, my notation is bad. Should that read $f((x,y)) = (x,y)$?

Comment: @alg2 That is what I meant. It is common to abbreviate $f((x,y))$ by $f(x,y)$.

Comment: Wait, so $f((x,y)) = (x,y)$ is bad too? I guess I'm just really confused. What should I be writing?

Comment: @alg2 Perhaps I should refrain from answering that until I understand your main question a little better. In your question, does $f$ represent the same thing throughout?

Comment: I meant for $f$ to be the identity mapping. (i.e. in $\mathbb{R}$ it takes scalars to scalars, in $\mathbb{R}^2$ it takes $(x,y)$ pairs to $(x,y)$ pairs, where $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, and so on)

Comment: And you want to find the jacobian for all $n$, is that it?

Comment: I'm more interested in _how_ to find it. I realize that it's just an $n \times n$ identity matrix (or at least I really hope so, otherwise I'm worse off than I thought). This is a simpler version of another problem where I'm having the same kind of conceptual error. I just chose the identity mapping because it's straightforward.

To elaborate a bit, I'm aware of how to find the Jacobian for functions like $f(x,y) = (g(x,y), h(x,y))$. I'm just not sure what to do with nested tuples.

Comment: @alg2 Firstly let me apologize because I misunderstood something and it was entirely my fault. When you wrote $f(x,y)=(x,y)$, I interpreted it as $x\in \mathbb R$ and $y\in \mathbb R$, so I thought you were looking at the case $n=1$, hence all the confusion.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I was being sloppy with my notation. Sorry about that.

Comment: No, you weren't. Everything is fine with your notation (at the start). I'm now going to tell you something and I hope it might help you. If after this you don't understand what is going on, I will type an answer. It shouldn't be $\dfrac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)}$, but rather $\dfrac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n, y_1, \ldots , y_n)}$.

Comment: Sorry, it's not clicking. Why $y_1,\ldots,y_n$ and not a repeated $x_1,\ldots,x_n$?

Comment: See notation used [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant). The denominator must be a point of the domain, in this case, $\mathbb R^n\times \mathbb R^n$.

Comment: That's not quite what I meant. I mean why $\partial(x_1,\ldots,x_n,y_1,\ldots,y_n)$ instead of $\partial(x_1,\ldots,x_n,x_1,\ldots,x_n)$? It seems like we'd just repeat the basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ again.

Comment: Because You're second $x_1$ is suppose to the note the $n+1^{\text{th}}$ coordinate. From the get go I think using $\mathbb R^n\times \mathbb R^n$ instead of $\mathbb R^{n+n}$ just brings confusion. Is it OK with you if I give an answering dealing with $\mathbb R^m$ instead of what you wrote?

Comment: Yeah, that'd be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, I'll deal with the case $\varphi\colon \mathbb R^m\to \mathbb R^m, x\mapsto x$.

Any $x\in \mathbb R^m$ equals $(x_1, \ldots , x_m)$, for some $x_1, \ldots ,x_m\in \mathbb R$.

For each $i\in \{1, \ldots, m\}$, let $\varphi_i$ denote the *scalar* map $\colon \mathbb R^m\to \mathbb R, x\mapsto x_i$.

The [jacobian matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) $J_\varphi$ is thus the $m\times m$ matrix that follows:
$$\begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{\partial \varphi _1}{\partial x_1}& \ldots &\dfrac{\partial \varphi_1}{\partial x_m}\\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\ \dfrac{\partial \varphi_m}{\partial x_1} & \ldots & \dfrac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x_m}\end{bmatrix}.$$

Since $\dfrac{\partial \varphi _i}{\partial x_j}$ is the null function whenever $i\neq j$ and it is the map $x\mapsto 1$, whenever $i=j$, the jacobian matrix is the identity matrix.

Comment: The above can be translated to your question which essentially is $m=2n$. But the setting in your question is more troublesome and I see no advantage in using it over the one in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer!

Comment: @al92 You're welcome.